# Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement ERROR in csharp

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting VB.net to C# for this code:

```
Dim files() As String
files = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\text", "*.txt") 
Dim filename As String
Dim file As String
For Each file In files
filename = Path.GetFileName(file)
```

I tried this in C# but got the error

> Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement ERROR in csharp

```
string[] files;
files = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\text", "*.txt");
string[] filenameMove;
string filename;
string file;

foreach (file  in files)
  filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
```

Comment: so whats the question?

Comment: For Each file in VB.NET must also have an ending `Next` statement.

Comment: Exactly!! Whats the question dude? Anything went wrong?

Comment: VB allows including the type in a For Each, but also (surprise) allows you to be sloppy by referencing a previously declared variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
foreach(var file in files)
```

You need to specify the type you're looping through or use `var`

You already declared a variable called file though. So you'd have to use a different name

```
foreach(var f in files)
{
  filename = Path.GetFileName(f);
}
```

(Although with your logic you're just overwriting the filename on each iteration, so unless you only want the last filename, I'm not sure what the purpose of it is).

Comment: I am gtting different error now : after i put var, Error 1 A local variable named 'file' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'file', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else E:\MyTextProcess\MyTextProcess\Program.cs

Comment: That's right. You already declared a variable called file. Use something else. See update.

Comment: Another way to say the same: In C#, a `foreach` statement cannot (re)use a variable already declared in an "outer" scope as its iteration variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at **[foreach](http://www.dotnetperls.com/foreach)** syntax.

```
  Foreach(Type varName in array)
  {
      filename = Path.GetFileName(varName);
  }
```

that `Type` and array should be of same `Type` or you could use `var` variable like this

```
  Foreach(var varName in array)
  {
      filename = Path.GetFileName(varName);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That here are u missing var and string

try this

```
    foreach (var file  in files)


    foreach (string file  in files)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] files;
files = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\text", "*.txt");
string[] filenameMove;
string filename;
//string file;

//foreach (file  in files)
  foreach (string file  in files)
  filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
```