# Type and identifier are both required in foreach statement

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have an Active Directory searcher in VB.NET which I'm converting to C#.NET and am getting the error above.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165795/type-and-identifier-are-both-required-in-a-foreach-statement-error-in-csharp) post which is the exact same error but in a different set of circumstances. From reading the linked post, it seems that the error is caused by not specifying the data type which you are trying to loop through... What I can't workout though is with my searcher, which data type I should actually be specifying!

Here is the code as it stands currently with the error;

```
foreach (Result in SearcherResults)
    {
        OnResultFound(new ResultFoundEventArgs(Result));
        ResultCount += 1;
    }
```

I have tried;

```
foreach (var Result in SearcherResults)
```

as suggested in the other post, and I have also tried;

```
foreach (SearchResult Result in SearcherResults)
```

thinking that as Result is defined as a SearchResult type this may work but both of these attempts error with

`"A local variable named 'Result' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'Result', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"`

I imagine I am missing something horrifically obvious, but if anyone's got any suggestions I'd be very grateful.

Comment: What is unclear about "A local variable named 'Result' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'Result', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"?

Comment: you already have a Results variable defined, use another variable name...`(var r in SearcherResults)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> thinking that as Result is defined as a SearchResult type this may work but both of these attempts error with

This gives me the idea that you have actually defined `Result` before your foreach loop *on purpose*.

Actually, you define it *in* your foreach loop.

Wrong:

```
SearcherResult Result;
foreach (SearcherResult Result in SearcherResults) 
{
    ...
}
```

The compiler will see the two `Result` definitions as two separate variables with the same name, hence the error.

Correct:

```
foreach (SearcherResult Result in SearcherResults) 
{
    ...
}
```

The variable Result is defined as you define your foreach loop.

Comment: oerkelens... Thank you! You were 100% right, knew it would be simple, thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Exacly as this error states:

> A local variable named 'Result' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'Result', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

you have variable with name `Result` defined somewhere else. Just change its name:

```
foreach (var searcherResult in SearcherResults)
{
    OnResultFound(new ResultFoundEventArgs(searcherResult));
    ResultCount += 1;
}
```